# How to create Radio Buttons in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8, dlradiobutton

How to make radio button in Objective c.I want to switch at different view controller when hit radio button. Want to make simple two radio buttons.

Comment: there is not any default property for radio button. You need to set radio image to button.

Comment: `[btnRedio1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];` setImage on Button When you press button  and setIUncheck Image on other Button  like `[btnRedio2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: `UISegmentedController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to set different image to button with its state in ViewDidLoad.

   ```
   [yourbutton setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"Radio_button_off.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [yourbutton setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"Radio_button_on.png"]forState: UIControlStateSelected];

   - (void) btnAction:(UIButton*)button{
        button.selected = !button.selected;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Use the selected / unselected state of any UIButton.
 Use the `setImage:forState` to assign selected / unselected radio images/
When the button is pressed, iterate over all the buttons of the groups and set the appropriate one to selected.

That's it!